# How to call SQLPS from TSql in SQL Server 2008

Tags: t-sql, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

I see lots of examples on running SQLPS from SQL Server Agent, but how do you call a powershell script from TSQL on demand?

I'm replacing a C# CLR function with a PowerShell script. The script will simply get a path and date modified for files in a directory structure.

What's the command to call a PowerShell script from a T-SQL stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
set @sql = 'powershell.exe -file "YourScript.ps1" -nologo'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Comment: Okay, that worked. Thanks. One more question. I am running the following code :  'powershell.exe (Get-Childitem G:\11764 -include *.* -recurse) | select LastWriteTime,Name,Directory' 

The problem is that when I pipe it to the select statement, it causes an error, saying that it isnt a proper command. I'm assuming that it is trying to pipe to a CMD command when it needs to be powershell. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: Nevermind, thanks for the help. I fixed that part myself. Just added double quotes.